# devexpress xtrareport binding multiple list datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I am attaching Class Detail as my DataSource to the report;

```
class Detail
{ 
public string Name { get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
public string City { get; set;}
public List<Transaction> tran { get; set; }
}
class Transaction
{
public string TransactionDate { get; set; }
public string TransactionDescription { get; set; } 
}
```

and in my query i send it as List.

```
public List GetAccount(string account) {
List detail = new List();
sql ....
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
detail.Add(new Detail()
{
  Name= dr["name"].Equals(DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : dr["name"].ToString(),
 .....
  tran = GetTransactionDetail(account)// calling a list

 }); 
}
return detail;
}

public List<Transaction> GetTransactionDetail(string account)
{
....
}
```

and at the Form1.cs

```
XtraReport1 rep = new XtraReport1();
printControl1.PrintingSystem = rep.PrintingSystem;
var ls = query.GetAccount(accountNo);
rep.DataSource = ls;
rep.CreateDocument();
```

in the report i should get a list of transaction details but i get only the first row.
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your report is designed. Usually you need a separate band (DetailReport) for all of the details to be visible (if you're using XRTable).

Answer (score 0):

Sir you should use `DataSet` and `query.GetAccount(accountNo)` returns `DataTable`
Then try like this. It works for me.

```
XtraReport1 rep = new XtraReport1();
printControl1.PrintingSystem = rep.PrintingSystem;
var ds = new ds("TestDataSet");
var ls = query.GetAccount(accountNo);
ds.Tables.Add(ls);
rep.DataSource = ds;
rep.DataMember = ls.TableName;
rep.CreateDocument();
```